# Unable to access props from functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have a provider and context setup in my React project.
The context extends firebase.
Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)

export default FirebaseContext;
```

Using a class component I'm able to access firebase like so:

```
import { withFirebase } from "../components/Firebase";
```

my export is like so:

```
export default withFirebase(Admin);
```

In this way inside my component(Admin) I'm able to access `this.props.firebase` and execute.

My problem is I have a functional component which is a child of a child of Admin.
Admin -> child component -> child component(this one is the one)

Here I do the same import withFirebase as above
and wrap the export in withFirebase()

```
const MinistriesAdminForm = props => {

  const [ministries, setMinistries ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    this.props.firebase.getMinistries(this.state.currentOrganization).on("value", data => {
    const ministriesObject = data.val();

    setMinistries(ministriesObject);

    });
  })
}

export default withFirebase(MinistriesAdminForm);
```

In the above I get an error on this.props.firebase 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.props` is for class based components.

Functional components do not have an instance, `props` is a regular argument. You should access it like `props.firebase`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.firebase.getMinistries(this.state.currentOrganization).on("value", data => {
    const ministriesObject = data.val();

    setMinistries(ministriesObject);

    });
```

`this.state.currentOrganization` is also an invalid statement. If it's a local state provided by `useState` you should access like a normal variable

```
const [currentOrganization, setOrganization] = useState('foo')
/*...*/
props.firebase.getMinistries(currentOrganization)
```

Or if `currentOrganization` comes from `props`

```
props.firebase.getMinistries(props.currentOrganization)
```